# Is it possible to create a backup RAID 5 on a nas by replacing 1 drive at a time?

Tags: raid, network-attached-storage, qnap

During a recent office relocation my QNAP TS-509 (RAID 5 with 4 2tb WD Red) wouldn't boot properly and fooling around trying to correct that I lost the volume. As I was expanding my very limited understanding of RAID and lamenting the fact the the reconstruction is going to be a giant time suck PITA it occurred to me that after its up, if I were to replace each drive and let the raid rebuild I would have a copy of it once all drives had been swapped out.  Is this an accurate understanding?  So if I lost the volume again I could shut down, swap all 4 drives , reboot and I should be up?  Thanks, first time post so lmk if I left out anything important.

Comment: If at all, that can only work with an offline volume, without *any* changes. Any interim change destroys the consistency of the removed disks, rendering your backup attempt moot.

Answer (score 1):

No. Don't do that. Do a proper dump.

QNAP is likely running Linux, and its RAID is likely a widely known Linux software MD RAID. So try to connect all disks to Linux machine and see if it is able to rebuild an array.

If it doesn't help and you don't know how to recover the data, better find a professional data recovery service.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? Possibly? Would I recommend it? No.

RAID isn't backup. Implement a proper backup of the data on the NAS. If you need to rebuild or recover it, use the backup to restore your data.